# Correct hypothesis test to use here?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, method-comparison

I have 5 samples from which I gathered data at 5 separate time points (days).

Each day I observe the distribution of some RV.

When I plot the distribution for each day it sort of looks like this for one sample.

[image: Distribution for each day]

There's supposed to be a distribution change after day 0, but I'm trying to see if there's a difference between Days 1-6. The distributions between days look kind of different in the plot, but I'm pretty sure that's just due to noise.

If I look at my other samples the amount the distributions varies for a fixed day between samples is more than the distribution varies between days. In other words, if I look at the distribution at Day 1 for samples 1 and 2, the distribution varies more than it does between Day 1 and 2 for either sample.

I can see that in plots, but I'm trying to show that with math. The way I've found is to use the Kolmogorov Smirnov test which in my limited understanding tells me the "distance" between two distributions. The distance I calculate between days is around the same as the distance I calculate between samples. Is that the best way to do this? Is there another way to express what I'm trying to say:

While there is a difference in distributions between days in Sample X, the difference is no greater than the difference between samples for a fixed day. As such we chose to omit this feature in our model.

Another thing to note is that using p-values don't work too well in my scenario since I have >4000 samples of the rv each day.

Please let me know thanks :)